# How do I apply php to 6 individual select elements when trying to retrieve the form data from them?

Tags: php, html, css, http, post

I have only recently got my head around PHP and got stuck when duplicating a single piece of code multiple times. I have made everything have their unique variables and linked them to the right name attributes in the input element and select elements. I don't really know much to do with PHP but I have looked around a lot but haven't managed to find any solution. 

When I select an option (Subaru) then click submit it comes up with this:

You have selected: Subaru

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: modelSelectRight in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 28

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: yearSelectRight in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 34

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/home.php on line 34
```

I will provide the relevant code in CSS as well as HTML/PHP.
It may be an obvious mistake but please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks.

Please note that the HTML file's extension is .php

```css
body{
    display:block;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#wrapper{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#top_header{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:;
    text-align: left;
}
#top_nav{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
#top_nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.list_boxes{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#main_body{
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
#sec1{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #D3D3D;
}
.circle_image{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:none;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px double black;
}
.button_wrap{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.ListItemsDecoration li{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.button_wrap select{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 200px;;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#symbol{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 27.25%;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#compare_button{
    margin-top:100px;
    width: 79px;
}
#sec2{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #D3D3D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['makeSelectLeft'] as $selectMake1)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectMake1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['modelSelectLeft'] as $selectModel1)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectModel1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['yearSelectLeft'] as $selectYear1)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectYear1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['makeSelectRight'] as $selectMake2)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectMake2;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['modelSelectRight'] as $selectModel2)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectModel2;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
        foreach ($_POST['yearSelectRight'] as $selectYear2)
        {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectYear2;
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />  <!--Specifies the character encoding of the document-->   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
        <title>Home</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
        
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <h1>CarCompare</h1>
            </header>
            <nav id="top_nav">
                <ol>
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Home</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Contact Us</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>About Us</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Cars</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Trucks</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Bikes</li></a> |
                    <a class="list_boxes"><li>Reviews</li></a> |
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <div id="main_body">
                <h3>COMPARE</h3>
                    <aside id="sec1">
                <form method="post" action="#" class="CompareWrapperListed">
                        <nav class="ListItemsDecoration">                
                            <li><div class="circle_image"></div></li>
                                <div class="button_wrap">
                                        <li><select name="makeSelectLeft[]" id="1MakeSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Make</option>
                                            <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                                            <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
                                            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </li><select name="modelSelectLeft" id="1ModelSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Model</option>
                                            <option value="Lancer">Lancer</option>
                                            <option value="Evolution">Evolution</option>
                                            <option value="Camry">Camry</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <li><select name="yearSelectLeft" id="1YearSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Year</option>
                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                        </select>   
                                </div>
                        </nav>
                    </aside>
                <input type="submit" name="Compare" id="compare_button" />
                    <aside id="sec2">
                        <nav class="ListItemsDecoration">
                            <li><img class="circle_image"></img></li>
                                <div class="button_wrap">
                                        <nav></nav>
                                        <li><select name="makeSelectRight" id="1MakeSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Make</option>
                                            <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                                            <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
                                            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <li><select name="makeModelRight" id="1ModelSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Model</option>
                                            <option value="Lancer">Lancer</option>
                                            <option value="Evolution">Evolution</option>
                                            <option value="Camry">Camry</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <li><select name="makeYearRight" id="1YearSelect" type="option"></li>
                                            <option>Year</option>
                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                        </nav>
                </form>
                    </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CarcompanyNewJavascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to choose multiple options from each select dropdown? If so, then you need to add 'multiple' with the select tag

Comment: Yes and display the users selection on another page

Answer (score 1):

you only need to check one time for a post then you check that the values not empty before doing your loop

```
<?php
    //check once if is posted
    if(isset($_POST['Compare'])){
       //check if the post value empty or not
       if(!empty($_POST['makeSelectLeft'])){
           foreach ($_POST['makeSelectLeft'] as $selectMake1)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectMake1;
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['modelSelectLeft'])){
           foreach ($_POST['modelSelectLeft'] as $selectModel1)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectModel1;
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['yearSelectLeft'])){
           foreach ($_POST['yearSelectLeft'] as $selectYear1)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectYear1;
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['makeSelectRight'])){
           foreach ($_POST['makeSelectRight'] as $selectMake2)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectMake2;
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['modelSelectRight'])){
           foreach ($_POST['modelSelectRight'] as $selectModel2)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectModel2;
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['yearSelectRight'])){
           foreach ($_POST['yearSelectRight'] as $selectYear2)
           {
            echo "You have selected :" .$selectYear2;
           }
       }
    }
?>
```

then in your html do your select like this to choose multiple

```
<select name="makeSelectLeft[]" id="1MakeSelect" type="option" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: I thought it wouldnt be !empty because the variable isn't NULL. Isn't !empty the opposite of isset?

Comment: @Dale if nothing is selected it should be empty so we check if it is (not "!" empty), the foreach loop will fail if no value was posted , the [ ] at the end name="makeSelectLeft[] gives the html value the ability to be an array, but if no value is selected it should still be empty another way is to count the posts like $yearselectrightcount = count($_POST['yearSelectRight']); then checking if its not 0 and then do the loop to retrieve the data

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply, my computer stuffed up. When I add the multiple=""multiple" it stops it from becoming a drop-down. Would you have a suggestion for this? I tried adding it to the form element but there was no luck

Comment: @Dale it will look like a drop down that is already open is that what it looks like?

Comment: in your case i think it might be better to use checkboxes, you can use <lable> then write the name when the user clicks the name it will check the checkbox and you can style it with css to make it look nice , multiple selection for drop down always change the way it looks and for the user to selected multiple options they have to hold down the control key so this way is not very user friendly, i have heard of some jquery plugins that can do this but never used it before.

Comment: Reason I need a dropdown is because I am intending on having lots of information in the dropdown. Reason I don't really like the already open dropdown is because i need a placeholder name to it. I don't have the intention of them selecting multiple ones under the dropdown but just one, for 3 seperate dropdowns.